# Using find to locate files that have non-printable characters in their names

Tags: shell, find

In one folder, there are many files whose filenames contain Non-Printable and Special Characters, such as "\201". If I directly enter it. I will not find them. How can I find them?

The files shows in bash

[image]

The file shows in emacs.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Non-Printable and Special" here. What problem are you having? Are you just not quoting properly? `\201` isn't a particularly tricky filename (nor is `ȁ`, which is \u0201 if that's what you mean). When you say "find", how are you trying to find them?

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you for your fast reply.  For example, one filename is "\220Senno.flac". If I use command "find . -iname '*\220*'". I cannot find it. I am wondering which command to show this file by using find function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at least with GNU `find`, you can search for a name that contains non-printable characters.

The set of non-printable characters depends on your locale. If you specify that you are working with the C locale, non-printable characters are those with an ASCII code < 32 or an ASCII code >= 127.

```
LC_ALL=C find -name '*[^[:print:]]*'
```

Here `[^[:print:]]` represents any non-printable character.

Answer (score 0):

For you example of "\220Senno.flac", you need to quote the `\`:

```
find . -iname '\\220*'
```

`-iname` takes a shell pattern, not a literal string, so `\` need escaping.

Comment: Then this likely isn't your actual filename. Why do you believe this is the filename? Is it really "backslash-two-two-zero-uppercaseS..."? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: I update my question with figure.The filename contains \220

Comment: Backlash is not part of the filename. It's part of the octal code that follows. \220 is ASCII code 144 (A4h). I suspect this may be UTF-8, i.e. that it is bound to the next char (S = 53h). UTF-8 code A453 corresponds to the glyph [Yi Syllable Nyuo](https://gl.letrag.com/caracter.php?id=42067). Could this be the expected character @yuxuan?

Comment: Ooops, this is is not a valid utf-8 sequence. This might rather be UTF-16, where A453 would be 厤 and the whole filename `\220Senno` would translate to 厤湥潮. Does it makes sense to you @yuxuan?

Comment: @xhienne I guess so. I think many files have the same things and I want to remove them because this is not my expectation.

Comment: @xhienne Now I understand it. Thank you very much. Now I can use `find -name '*[^[:print:]]*'`to find them. I am wondering how I can just search with `\220`.